# for loop returns only first array element in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I want to iterate over the below array received from a curl response and print the values of all the "path" properties on a new line but I am getting unwanted results everytime (may be i dont know how to do)

```
{
"values": [
    {
        "old": {
            "path": "textfile.txt"
        },
        "size":1
    },
    {
        "old": {
            "path": "text1file.txt"
        },
        "size":1
    }
]
}
```

Below is my bash script which returns only the first value, also when i try to get the length it always returns 1 instead of 2

```
FILES=$(curl "https://url" | jq '(.values[].old.path)')
echo "$FILES"
echo "length is: ${#FILES[@]}"
for i in "${FILES[@]}"; do
    echo "num1 ${i}"
done
```

The response received for line 2 is below:

```
"textfile.txt"
"text1file.txt"
```

The response received for line 3:

```
length is: 1
```

The expected response of line 5 is:

```
num1 "textfile.txt"
num1 "text1file.txt"
```

But instead it gives:

```
num1 "textfile.txt"
     "text1file.txt"
```

PS: I am doing the above script in bitbucket pipelines to implement CD process.

Does any one know what's wrong in the above `for` loop?

EDIT: I also tried the below script it still gives only the first value.

```
  curl -H 'Content-Type:application/json' https://url >> myfilenames.json
  for i in $(jq -r '.values[].old.path' myfilenames.json); do
      echo "${i}"
  done
```

Comment: `FILES=$(curl "https://url" | jq '(.values[].old.path)')` is _not_ an array assignment, but assignment to a variable

Comment: I edited the new way of loop I learnt from some of the stackoverflow answers, it doesnt work as well. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @nz_pree, what "new way of loop" are you talking about? The `for item in "${array[@]}"` approach works only if your value is truly an array. `files=$(curl ... | jq ...)` does not create an array, so you can't use `"${files[@]}"` with it. Use the code in the answer by Shawn to create a true array, and _then_ `"${files[@]}"` will work properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to save the paths in a bash array, you need something like:

```sh
mapfile -t files < <(curl ... | jq '.values[].old.path')
echo "Length is ${#files[@]}"
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    echo "num1 $file"
done
```

(See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization))

---

Just in case you don't want the double quotes around the path even though they're present in your question, use `jq -r`.

If you don't want the quotes and the paths might have newlines in them (and you have a development version of `jq` installed):

```sh
mapfile -d '' -t files < <(curl ... | jq -0 '.values[].old.path')
```

The `-0` option is not (yet) in an official release. So this version will be more useful:

```sh
mapfile -d '' -t files < <(curl ... | jq -j '.values[] | "\(.old.path)\u0000"')
```

If you're using a version of `bash` older than 4.4, see [Bash FAQ 005](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005#Reading_NUL-delimited_streams) for a workaround using `read` in a loop instead of `mapfile`.

Comment: This is really no better than just reading the output of jq and iterating, and does not address the problem of newlines in the paths.  IOW, there's no point in putting it in an array if you do this.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Er, I included an example that handles newlines in raw strings. Though admittedly it requires a development version of `jq` as 1.6 doesn't support the `-0` option. And just iterating doesn't give you what the OP wants with first printing out the number of records and then the records themselves.

Comment: (Without `-r/-0/-j`, `jq` will output newlines in strings as `\n` escapes, not actual newlines)

Comment: @WilliamPursell, _if combined with_ iterating over the array's contents properly, this is definitely much better practice than what the OP was doing earlier, as any of the NUL-based variants will work properly with all possible filenames. That said, I do agree that to be fully complete this needs to show how to iterate over the array (`for file in "${files[@]}"; do ...`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy OP already seems to know how to do that part so I left it out. It's just getting values into an array that they were having problems with.

Comment: Rereading the question, I agree that they know how to do it; I'm not sure they know _when it's appropriate_, as they've experimented with other mechanisms as well.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks alot for your answer. I tried the script suggested by you as below:
- mapfile -t files << (curl "https://url" | jq '.values[].old.path')
             - echo "Length is ${#files[@]}"
             - for file in "${files[@]}"; do
             - echo "num1:${file}"
             - done
But it givesthis :
 bash: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/tmp/bashScript7963299335666580030.sh: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: @nz_pree I think you removed a space where there should be one and added a space where there shouldn't be one.

Comment: @Shawn yes i corrected the space thing and it gave correct result for length(i.e, 2) but it printed only the first filename

Comment: @nz_pree Works for me.